# Angular directive dynamic button text variable not evaluated?

Tags: javascript, css, button, angularjs, directive

I am trying to create iphone style Toggle Button with css in angular

But problem is dynamic button text variable not evaluated first time "{{v1['btn2']}}" , but working fine with static text

URL for jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/z5SNc/3/

Below is my code:

```
angular.module('test').controller('myctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.v1={
        "status":"1",
        "btn1":"On",
        "btn2":"Off"
    }
     $scope.v2={
        "status":"1"
     }
});

angular.module('test').directive('btnSwitch', function(){

  return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    require :  'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          render();
        };
        var render=function(){
          var val = ngModel.$viewValue; 

          var open=angular.element(element.children()[0]);

          var closed=angular.element(element.children()[1]);
          if(val)
          {
            closed.html(closed.attr("text"));
            closed.addClass('btnOnSelected');  
            open.html("&nbsp;");
            open.removeClass('btnOffSelected');  
          }
          else{
              open.html(open.attr("text")); 
              open.addClass('btnOffSelected');  
              closed.removeClass('btnOnSelected');  
              closed.html("&nbsp;");
          }
        };
        element.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(toggle);             
        });
        function toggle() {
           var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
           ngModel.$setViewValue(!val); 
           render();          
        } 
        if(!ngModel){  

          return;          
        }  
         render();
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="pull-left" btn-switch ng-model="v1['status']">
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOff" text="{{v1['btn1']}}">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOn btnOnSelected" text="{{v1['btn2']}}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearFix" style="height:20px"></div>
        <hr />
         <div class="pull-left" btn-switch ng-model="v2['status']">
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOff" text="On">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOn btnOnSelected" text="Off"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the directive first runs, attributes have not been interpolated yet.

**Solution is used is $timeout**

Below is the Working jsfiddle:

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/sHZdg/5/)</kbd>

**HTML Part**

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="pull-left" btn-switch ng-model="v1['status']">
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOff" text="{{v1['btn1']}}">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOn btnOnSelected" text="{{v1['btn2']}}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearFix" style="height:20px"></div>
        <hr />
         <div class="pull-left" btn-switch ng-model="v2['status']">
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOff" text="On">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="pull-left btnCS btnOn btnOnSelected" text="Off"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test').controller('myctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.v1={
        "status":"1",
        "btn1":"On",
        "btn2":"Off"
    }
     $scope.v2={
        "status":"1"
     }
});
```

**Directive Code:**

```
angular.module('test').directive('btnSwitch', function($timeout){

  return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    require :  'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){


        ngModel.$render = function() {
          render();
        };

        var render=function(){
          var val = ngModel.$viewValue; 
            console.log(val);          
          var open=angular.element(element.children()[0]);

          var closed=angular.element(element.children()[1]);
          if(val)
          {
            closed.html(closed.attr("text"));
            closed.addClass('btnOnSelected');  
            open.html("&nbsp;");
            open.removeClass('btnOffSelected');  
          }
          else{
              open.html(open.attr("text")); 
              open.addClass('btnOffSelected');  
              closed.removeClass('btnOnSelected');  
              closed.html("&nbsp;");
          }
        };


        element.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(toggle);             
        });


        function toggle() {
           var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
           ngModel.$setViewValue(!val); 
           render();          
        } 

        if(!ngModel){  

          return;          
        }  
        //console.log(ngModel.$viewValue)
        $timeout(function(){
            //var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
            //ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
            render();
        }, 0);            
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to initialize the value the first time through.  Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sHZdg/.

I added these two lines at the end of your directive:

```
var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
```

This will set the initial value before you call `render()` to set up the `$scope` values.

Comment: I have check and put the console.log() and it initial values for ngModel.$viewValue is NaN, can you check this url @ http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/sHZdg/1/ 
Why the Value is NaN ?

Comment: Yeah, your right.  I'm not sure either.  I'll check it out when I've got a moment.  In fact, if I change the code to this: `ngModel.$setViewValue(NaN);` it also works. :)

Answer (score 1):

When the directive first runs, attributes have not been interpolated yet.

I suggest using $eval instead of {{}}s:

```
<div class="pull-left btnCS btnOff"              text="v1['btn1']">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="pull-left btnCS btnOn btnOnSelected" text="v1['btn2']"></div>
```

```
closed.html(scope.$eval(closed.attr("text")));
...
open.html(scope.$eval(open.attr("text")));
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/55V77/)</kbd>